# How can I implement css condition inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created a function to filter my images based on their categories using React, the filter function works great, but when I filter my images they take the left side and I wanted to be centered.

I want to implement this condition of centered images inside the filter function so when so my function run I could filter and center my images

I tried but I couldn't find out solutions. Thanks

```
const filterModel = (category) => { 

    if(category === 'all') {
        setModelsCards(Models);
        return;
    }
    const newModel = Models.filter((model)=> model.category === category);
    setModelsCards(newModel);
    
    
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "css condition". Typically you would have your css properties in a seperate file and assign the appropriate css classes from the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `css` in a sperate file and add a `class` with some styling to it for centering the elements. After that when filtering your images assign that `class` to the `Image Component` or `img tag`.